# Is there an adjective to describe that someone is being brought somewhere?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective to describe the girls in these sentences:

> 1. Girl gets a new boyfriend, so she no longer walks to school.
> 2. A daughter is driven to school everyday by her father.
> 3. A teenager does not go to work alone, her older brother walks her there on his way to his job.

Answer (score 3):

All the girls in your examples are being ***escorted***.

> [**escorted**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/escorted):
>
> Adjective (not comparable)
>
> With or having an
>   escort.
>
> [**escort**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/escort):
>
> noun
>
> The definition of an escort is something or
>   someone who accompanies a person or thing, often for security or
>   protection.